# LZ4 compressed text is larger than uncompressed

Tags: compression, lzw, lz4

I have read that lz4 algorithm is very fast and has pretty good compression. But in my test app compressed text is larger than the source text. What is the problem?

```
srand(time(NULL));
std::string text;
for (int i = 0; i < 65535; ++i)
    text.push_back((char)(0 + rand() % 256));

cout << "Text size: " << text.size() << endl;

char *compressedData = new char[text.size() * 2];
int compressedSize = LZ4_compress(text.c_str(), text.size(), compressedData);

cout << "Compressed size: " << compressedSize << endl;
```

I also tried LZ4_compress, but result is the same. But if I generate string with same symbols or say with two different symbols, then compression is present.

Comment: What do you expect from compression of random data not having patterns (your question is actually the answer) ?

Comment: Text size: 65535
Compressed size: 65793

Comment: noise (== random data) is not compressible. It's a core property of a random source. For your test to be valid, you should better load some real text into your buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at a [description of the LZ4 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_%28compression_algorithm%29).  It references common substrings within the compressed text.  It uses the already output text as a dictionary.

Random text or any other material without repeating sequences of any length will not compress well using it.  For that plaintext, a bit compression algorithm will probably do better.