# Why doesn't lz4 keep small/uncompressible values uncompressed?

Tags: lossless-compression, lz4

When compressing small values (< 500 bytes or so), and for uncompressible [random values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839274/lz4-compressed-text-is-larger-than-uncompressed),
`lz4` returns data that is much larger than the original value (e.g. 27 bytes from 4).

When a large amount of such values is compressed separately (e.g. in a key-value storage), this adds up.

**Question is**: why doesn't lz4 use e.g. a separate [magic number](https://docs.fileformat.com/compression/lz4/#magic-number) for values that didn't become smaller after compression, leaving the original data as-is, and only adding 4 bytes of the overhead?

The same applies to many other compression formats.

Code with demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/gczy7f3k/2/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something you have to decide on higher level.

You can determine yourself if you want to compress, and add a marker (magic numbers) if the data is compressed.